# Youtube Player/React-Youtube: How to display thumbnail instead of loading spinner?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've been toying around with the React-Youtube package to render embedded Youtube videos on my small application I'm building. I've managed to implement the package correctly, however, when the player is ready, it does not display the thumbnail, but instead the loading spinner. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to display the thumbnail instead.

Here's what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMPaU.png

I've tried looking at the (short) documentation regarding the package and can't find anything: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube

Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks!

```
interface HighlightProps {
  highlight: extendedHighlight;
}

function HighlightVideo({ highlight }: HighlightProps) {
  const [isPlayerReady, setPlayerReady] = useState(false);

  const onPlayerReady: YouTubeProps["onReady"] = (event) => {
    // access to player in all event handlers via event.target
    event.target.pauseVideo();
  };

  const opts: YouTubeProps["opts"] = {
    height: "400",
    width: "550",
    playerVars: {
      // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
      autoplay: 1,
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setPlayerReady(true);
    }, 2500);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="max-w-2xl mx-auto mt-8 p-4 bg-white shadow-md rounded-md">
      {isPlayerReady ? (
        <>
          <div className="flex justify-center">
            <YouTube
              videoId={highlight.youtubeId}
              opts={opts}
              onReady={onPlayerReady}
            />
          </div>
          <HighlightDescription highlight={highlight} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <HighlightVideoSkeleton />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```